# How to modify twitter widget in css

Tags: html, css

I know how to change the size and colour of a twitter widget in `HTML` but I don't know how to do it in CSS can someone please help me?:)

Here is the twitter widget:

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/google" data-widget-id="405388412095438849">Tweets by @google</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: You would want to look for the element (maybe the `twitter-timeline` class) which specifies the `height`, `width`, and the `background-color` or `background` attributes.

Changing the appearance of widgets is usually a difficult thing to do though because they have many nested elements which inherit from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done only through the configurator. But you can try this:

Add attr (data-chrome="transparent")

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/google" data-widget-id="405388412095438849" data-chrome="transparent">Tweets by @google</a>
```

And then you may make somthing like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/76LwZ/250/